# I'm stuck with methods on this apparently simple exercise [Javascript]

Tags: javascript

The task is : Create an object named wizard. Add a method named makeSpell to the wizard object that will print any message you want to the console.

Add another method named playQuidditch that also prints a message.

Invoke both methods.

I have this code and doesn't work, really need help, thanks.

```
      var wizard = {
        makeSpell: function() {
          console.log('Crazy');
        }
      }
      var wizard = {
        playQuidditch: function() {
          console.log('Snitch');

        }
      }
      wizard.playQuidditch.makeSpell();
```

Comment: Declare `wizard` only once, and add the other method in it too. Then invoke `wizard.makeSpell()` and `wizard.playQuidditch()`. See [Object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer),

Comment: start by using this before continuing your learning of the JS language  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Answer (score 1):

@Teemu's option of merging your wizards and calling `makeSpell()` and `playQuidditch()` in separate statements is a good option:

```
const wizard = {
  makeSpell() {
    console.log('Crazy');
  },
  playQuidditch() {
    console.log('Snitch');
  }
}

wizard.playQuidditch();
wizard.makeSpell();
```

...but if you do want to chain together methods (sometimes called "fluent style coding", you can return `this` from the methods:

```
const wizard = {
  makeSpell() {
    console.log('Crazy');
    return this;
  },
  playQuidditch() {
    console.log('Snitch');
    return this;
  }
}

wizard
  .makeSpell()
  .playQuidditch();
```

This works because the return value from the method call is again the `wizard` object.

Comment: Thanks, I was missing some simple stuff, too many hours in row on this, my brain starts to melt, many thanks brother.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 ways of going about doing this.
The first is that you declare both of the functions in the wizard object at the same time and then call them.

```
var wizard = {
    makeSpell: function () {
        console.log('Crazy')
    },
    playQuidditch: function () {
        console.log('Snitch')
    }
}
wizard.makeSpell()
wizard.playQuidditch()
```

Or in the case where you must add the second function after the wizard object has already been created you can do it like this.

```
var wizard = {
    makeSpell: function () {
        console.log('Crazy')
    }
}

wizard = {...wizard, playQuidditch: function() { console.log('Snitch') } }

wizard.makeSpell()
wizard.playQuidditch()
```